# zoomToRect: Transform rectangle in a portrait image to the same image scaled to fit in landsape

Tags: ios, zooming, transform, scale, rect

i have the following problem.

i have UIImageView which displays an image in fullscreen in portrait mode 768 x 1024.

At position 200,200 i have a CGRect displayes with width 100,100 ...  CGRect(200,200,100,100)

Everything fine until here.

Now if i turn the device to landscape, the image gets scaled (scale to fit) and centered to the 1024 x 768 landscape format

No the problem is, that my rectangle 200,200,100,100 is too big... what seems to be logical because in lanscape the image is scaled down...

Question:
Is there a easy way to transform my rect 200,200,100,100 to fit to the landscape representation?

greetings,
nando

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [CALayerTransform3d](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html).  It lets you do pretty much any transform you can imagine and gives animation tools as well.  Setting the transform to rotate 90 degrees would put you in a landscape orientation.  Is that what you are looking for?